# Cascade dropdown list aka dependent dropdown list

Tags: views

Is there any way to make a cascade dropdown list aka dependent dropdown list for a "survey" content type?

Apart from the "survey" content type. I have three other content types: country, state and district. Each of these types are linked by entity references.

In the "survey" content I have created 3 dropdownlists, one for country, state and district. I am filling these lists with content types that I created specially for each one, that is to say, one content type for country, another for state and another for district.

So far so good. But I would like that when I change one of them, the others change dynamically. I have been able to do it with views, but not dynamically. Is there any solution without programming?

Or is there another way to do this?

I have read countless blogs and sites. However, I have not been able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this. One of the best options is to use AJAX dependent drop-down. It requires custom code however. There are some good articles in the net which I saw solving this. You may find a very decent example in the `examples` module [here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/-/blob/4.0.x/modules/ajax_example/src/Form/DependentDropdown.php)

What it does is to build one dropdown and on changing its value, to calculate the options for the next one and so on. I used such technique several times in my projects already.

Good luck!